# SQLAlchemy Session error

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy, addition

I have a problem with the session in SQLAlchemy, when i Add a row in the DB it's OK, but if i want to add another row without closing my app, It doesn't Add

This is the function in my Model:

```
def add(self,name):
    self.slot_name = name
    our_slot = self.session_.query(Slot).filter_by(slot_name = str(self.slot_name)).first()
    if our_slot:
        return 0
    else:
        self.session_.add(self)
        self.session_.commit()
        return 1
```

Comment: Try these two names: "Pacey Ennis", "Silvanus Yuliy". Do they both get added?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you commit your session. After committing a session, it is closed. Either you commit after you are done adding, or you open a new session after each commit. Also take a look at `Session.commit()`. You should probably read something about sessions in [SQLAlchemy's documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html).

Furthermore, suggest you do this:

```
def add(self,name):
    self.slot_name = name
    try:
        our_slot = self.session_.query(Slot)\
        .filter_by(slot_name = str(self.slot_name)).one()
        self.session_.add(self)
        return 1
    except NoResultFound:
        return 0
```

Of course, this only works if you expect exactly one result. It is considerd good practice to raise exceptions and catch them instead of making up conditions.

Comment: Thank you, but It didn't solve my problem, when I first add "A", then "B", the row of "A" is overwriten with "B".

I solve my problem renewing the object in my Controller.